# cp_ cannot stat: no such file or directory: Error copying files from localhost to k8s pod through Ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, cloud, rancher

I am trying to copy a test file (e.g. HelloWorld.txt) from my local machine to a k8s pod on Rancher through Ansible. The thing is that I am getting a cat: no such file or directory. I think I am getting this error because I am using the k8s_exec module to execute the cp command. And since I am using that, I think he is trying to make a copy not from my local machine to the pod but already inside the pod.

Here is the playbook:

```
---

- hosts: localhost #group of hosts on host file
  connection: local
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: '{{ ansible_playbook_python }}'
  collections:
    - community.kubernetes

  tasks:
    - name: Test Host Connection
      ping:
    - name: Get the pods in the specific namespace
      k8s_info:
        kubeconfig: '/etc/ansible/RCCloudConfig'
        kind: Pod
        namespace: redmine
      register: pod_list
    - name: Print pod names 
      debug:
         msg: "pod_list: {{ pod_list | json_query('resources[*].status.podIP')  }} "
    - set_fact:
        pod_names: "{{pod_list|json_query('resources[*].metadata.name')}}"
    - name: Copy Opatch zipfile to the Target Oracle_home
      k8s_exec:
        kubeconfig: '/etc/ansible/RCCloudConfig'
        namespace: redmine
        pod: "{{ pod_name | mandatory }}" #pod name
        command: cp /home/ansible/ansible/HelloWorld.txt /tmp  # copy from the current location to tmp
    - name: Show HelloWorld
      k8s_exec:
        kubeconfig: '/etc/ansible/RCCloudConfig'
        namespace: redmine
        pod: redminetisl-gitlab-69f7485b5d-52b5s #pod name
        command: cat /tmp/HelloWorld.txt
```

Ansible version:

```
ansible 2.9.9
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your guess is true, when you `exec` into container your command will be executed "inside" pod. In this case you'll be just copying file inside the pod which is not present.

Check out [kubectl cp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp) command. This is similar to `docker cp` command, which is copying file from host to container. You can use ansible `command module` to execute it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!! Is there any module, right now, that allows doing this in a more "agile "way? I  mean, some k8s module from community.kubernetes? I've looked to them all and none of them seemed to have such function as copying files.

Comment: More agile way would be not use this approach. You should check out configMap as file mount to pod: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by exit the container,and then cp the file into the container.
The problem is that I dont have the permission,so I need to quit the container ,and then type "sudo docker cp {file url} {containerID}:/opt/video" .

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit or a comment.